# Can I take backup of those tables which are created with NOLOGGING in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, backup

Can I take backup of those tables with data which were created with NOLOGIING option in Oracle.

Is it true that backup can not be taken for these tables and I can not restore my data if I have some crash or corruption.

Answer (score 1):

You can. From backup (rman) perspective there is no difference between LOGGING and NOLOGGING tables.

What you cannot do is restore through [NOLOGGING operation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/clauses005.htm). That means that if recover procedure will encounter such operation in archive log it is currently applying table will be marked as INVALID.